# TypeError: message() takes exactly 1 positional argument (29 given)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

```
def message(text):
    windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, 'Message', 0x20)
def otherfunc(startDistance, hops, i, formats, j):
    text = str('Distance: ' + str((startDistance + (hops * i))) + '. Format: ' + formats[j])
    threading.Thread(target=message, args=(text)).start()
```

For some reason this code produces the error that the function is getting 29 parameters, even though you can clearly see that text is a string.
Anyone has an idea how to solve?
Also, when calling message() without a thread, it works fine. The problem is that it's required it'll be in a thread.

Comment: You do know that `(text)` is the same as `text`? It's not a tuple. For that you need `(text,)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args` must be a sequence, but you are passing in the string:

```
threading.Thread(target=message, args=(text)).start()
```

Add a comma:

```
threading.Thread(target=message, args=(text,)).start()
```

You need at least one comma to make a tuple; in many contexts the parenthesis are optional:

```
>>> ('foo')
'foo'
>>> 'foo',
('foo',)
```

Without the comma, you are passing in a sequence of 29 individual characters to the `message()` function.

Comment: So far I got to work with threading with multi-parameters, did not know that was necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben: because that converts an *iterable* to separate elements in the tuple. Since `text` is a string, you get a tuple with individual characters, not a single element.